# How can you round the value of Javascript x and y coordinates

Tags: javascript, coordinates, rounding

I am displaying this variable,

```
var coords = 'Co-ords(' + hero.x + "," + hero.y + ')';
```

however when it displays it comes up like massive numbers like 294.99999999999

How can I round this down to say two decimal places?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`toFixed(n)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) to round to a specific number of decimal places.

Floating point numbers are not exact due to the way they represent numbers.  If you round to a certain number of decimal places, then this in accuracy will generally not be an issue.

```
var coords = 'Co-ords(' + hero.x.toFixed(2) + "," + hero.y.toFixed(2) + ')';
```

Comment: You've been busy since I took a Stack Overflow vacation.  Soon to be christened with the coveted 100K status :)